# Content editor webpart overrides Sharepoint CSS

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

Currently i use w3.css to a html page and use it in content editor webpart. The issue here is the CSS is affecting the whole page.How do i get the css to apply only to the content editor webpart.

i used the below link option 4 to add the content editor and the HTML file http://sharepoint.hannahswain.eu/2014/10/10/adding-a-code-snippet-to-page-content-on-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 1):

Using `!important` is a CSS hack and will get you in trouble at one point.
What happens when someone else uses the same `!important` hack **???**

Learn proper CSS, [Selectors](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) and its rules for [CSS Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and you will be able to master any CSS problem.

In your scenario you can wrap your content in a DIV

```
<div id='myCEWP'>
  <H1>Hello World!</H1>
</div>
```

And then apply your CSS only to that one H1 in the DIV :

```
<style>
   #myCEWP > H1 {
     color:green;
   }
</style>
```

Resources:

- [The 30 CSS Selectors you must memorize](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)
- [CSS Specificity, things you should know](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: I don't see i have danny, i just used w3schools please see the link for the css file used http://keoftpwu.blob.core.windows.net/ftp/Permanent/w3.css

Comment: Sorry, I am not a robot able to process that many lines of code. Learn the CSS basics. You can't run unless you learned how to walk first

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the code you have written? you may have to define a id to the Content editor element and apply css on those id. To override css we use **!important** after every attribute of css.

ex:

```
.CssClass{

color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: i have tweaked the css a bit which originally from w3scools. I uploaded it in https://keoftpwu.blob.core.windows.net/ftp/Permanent/w3.css .